# Can you get general user account activity via the Instagram API?

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api

I was wondering if it's possible to utilize the Instagram API with Python in order to gather info on follower account status to seek trends/activity/etc. for my platform. Basically I want to see what brands, etc. users engage with by using the API to see where the accounts who are part of my network go, what they click like on, where they leave a comment/what type of feedback they give/interact across brands. The accounts will consent to this of course, but is this even possible with the API anyways? I have seen services offer this for a fee, so I assumed it's possible somehow.

I assume that when a user leaves a comment it is stored in some database that you can then use the API to see if it matches with some ID or such -- if not then maybe there is a way to do this indirectly, i.e., some kind of background service that can see if a comment/ID matches a username without having to use the API itself. Basically I'm interested *if this is feasible/simple* -- I'm not too savvy!

This is meant for business and non-business/personal accounts -- also just for the fun of it too.

I have peeked at the API but it does not mention this, and no amount of searching narrows it down.

I know Facebook made some changes with their graph API which basically makes this a dead end on their platform without some possible hackaround if that is even theoretically possible.